# Adding a swipe listener to textView in Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm looking to add swipe detection to a textView. I'm using Anko with Kotlin, and when it comes to setting up the textView, I'm able to specify an onClick event, but when I try to add an onTouch or any other gesture, it seems to fail for me (the fix-it just alternates between telling me to put stuff in parentheses and take it out again). I've included the code below and would appreciate any help!

```
        relativeLayout{

        //Title
        var title = textView{
            text = "Title Name"
            textSize = 24f

            onClick{
                if(caller.returnedData != ""){
                    startActivity<MainActivity>()
                }
            }

            onTouch {
                // code to recognise touch here
            }


        }.lparams{
            centerHorizontally()
            topMargin = dip(180)
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing an OnGestureListener ?

Comment: I'm not really too sure how to add one?

Comment: Follow this : https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Anko it's easy like a sharm:

```
onTouch { view, event ->

                // .. Respond to touch events

                // put return value at the end:
                true    // or view.onTouchEvent(event) to proceed other events
}
```

It's equal to the following Java code:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      // ... Respond to touch events
      return true;
   }
});
```